# Is there a way to find the slope and the y-intercept of the best fit line (line regressions) manually?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

Let's say I have a really small data set. Quite simple. `x = [1,2,3,4,5]`, `y = [20,50,15,60,40]`

`x` is the independent variable. `y` is the dependent variable.

Mainly, I want to find out the slope value of the regression line i.e. 'm' in y = mx + b.
Is there a way to find the slope and the y-intercept of the best fit line (line regressions) manually (without using the `train_test_split` method from `sklearn` library)?

I tried the same thing in Ms Excel. I created two columns as x and y and their respective values. Then I selected the scatter plot with Linear regression feature and it immediately gave me the graph with the equation as y = 5x + 22.

I would like to perform this same task in python without using the `train_test_split` method just to know if there is an alternate way.

Comment: The `train_test_split` function has absolutely nothing to do with the calculation of the regression coefficients and intercept, which are computed with the `fit` method. Your exact question remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array([20,50,15,60,40]).reshape(-1,1)
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x,y)
```

Coefficients are saved as attributes:

```
lr.coef_, lr.intercept_
```

yields

```
(array([[5.]]), array([22.]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way! If the equation of the line would be `y = mx + b`, then-

> m (slope) = ( (x̅ * y̅) - x̅y̅ ) / ( (x̅)²-(x̅²) ) 
> b (y-intercept) = y̅ - mx̅
>
> x̅ means " mean (average) of values in x " 
> x̅y̅ means " mean of values in x * y " 
> (x̅)² means " square of mean of values in x " 
> (x̅²) means " mean of values in x * x " 
> x * y = [a, b, c, d, e] * [f, g, h, i, j] = [a*f, b*g, c*h, d*i, e*j]

If you have your data in simple lists (as mentioned in the question), you can get "m" and "b" this way:

```py
def best_fit_line(x_values, y_values):
    """Returns slope and y-intercept of the best fit line of the values"""

    mean = lambda l: sum(l)/len(l)
    multiply = lambda l1, l2: [a*b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]

    m = ( (mean(x_values)*mean(y_values) - mean(multiply(x_values, y_values))) / 
          (mean(x_values)**2             - mean(multiply(x_values, x_values))) )

    b = mean(y_values) - m*mean(x_values)

    return m, b
```

Example:

```py
# drive code for the second futction
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [20, 50, 15, 60, 40]

m, b = best_fit_line(x, y)

print(f"regression line: y = {round(m,2)}x + {round(b,2)}")

# Output:
# regression line: y = 5.0x + 22.0
```

As you see slope (m) is 5, and y-intercept (b) is 22.

[image]

If you have your data in numpy arrays, you can get "m" and "b" this way:

```py
def best_fit_line(x_values,y_values):
    """Returns slope and y-intercept of the best fit line of the values"""

    m = ( (x_values.mean()*y_values.mean() - (x_values*y_values).mean()) /
          (x_values.mean()**2              - (x_values**2).mean()) )

    b = y_values.mean() - m * x_values.mean()

    return m, b
```